# How to count with template lite

Tags: php, template-lite

I have a script like that.Below code creates a new `<li></li>`with every foreach object.
What i want is that creating `<li></li> html tag when counter is 4.`

```
  {foreach from=$books value=book}
    <div id="box1" class="box">
        <div id="box2" class="box"> <img src="{$imageUrl}/{$book.image}" width="145" height="205"></div>
        <div id="box3" class="box">
            <div class="baslik_kitap">{$book.title}</div>
            <div class="baslik_kitap2"></div>
            <div class="baslik_kitap"></div>
                <div class="baslik_kitap2">{$book.description|truncate:75:"..."}.</div>
                <div class="baslik_kitap"><a href="http://cmkzl.nokta.com/kitaplar/{$book.title}"><img src="{$imageUrl}/detaylar_btn.png" width="143" height="51"></a></div>

        </div>
    </div> 

            {/foreach}
```

Below code creates `<li></li>` with every object.

In order to create `<li></li>` when counter is 4

I wrote this

{foreach from=$books value=book}
{counter start=0 skip=1 print=false}
        
             
            
                {$book.title}
                
                
                    {$book.description|truncate:75:"..."}.

```
        </div>
    </div> 
            {if counter eq 4 } // here counter must be 0 and then foreach must continue with new counter
            {/foreach}
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm never used templatelite but from documentation it seems you can get what you want with something like this:

```
{counter start=0 print=false assign=mycounter}

{if $mycounter is div by 4}
   <li></li>
{/if}
```